# Drupal: Bulk term nodes links changing

Tags: php, drupal, redirect

We have pathauto and redirection modules. But they don't able us to do what we need. We need properly bulk update of category nodes urls, after changing category url. Properly means, old aliases should be removed and new redirections should come for old aliases.

```
Term url - "/category"
```

That has some child posts:

```
Node 1 url - "/category/node1"
Node 2 url - "/category/node2"
Node 3 url - "/category/node1000"
```

We have changed a term url We need to update all node urls to have latest term url.

```
Needed term url - "/category-new"

Needed Node 1 url - "/category-new/node1"
Needed Node 2 url - "/category-new/node2"
...
Needed Node 3 url - "/category-new/node1000"
```

Every old link should be redirected to new. While opening **/category/node1** user sees **/category-new/node1**

So old aliases need to be removed, and new need to appear. New redirections should appear for removed aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pathauto and redirect installed, you can bulk update your URL aliases at `/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk`